# Mouse hover over button (Auto Hide & Auto Expand)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the code for my html button with CSS everything looks fine, just wanted to modify the button code because it should auto hide when user move away cursor from the button and same when it hover over the button should auto expand, basically it should auto expand and auto reduce and dropdown arrow would add value to it.

I already have code little confusion about adding the above points

1. The Dropdown arrow key to button,
2. Auto Expand & reduce on mouse cursor movement over the button),

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}



function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #61CE70;
  color: blue;
  margin: 1px 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10pxpx;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropbtn {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url(https://search.png);
  float: input;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #086815;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 45px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align-last: max-width;
  border-color: #086815;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #067B0A4A;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-height: 550px;
  overflow: scroll;
  text-align-last: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  width: 390px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #7A7A7A;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}


/* ADD CSS */

div#myDropdown a span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}


/* width */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">SURAH</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search your Surah.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">1.Sureh Al-Fatihah <span>سُوْرَۃُ الفَاتِحَة</span> </a>
    <a href="#about">2.Sureh Al-Baqarah <span>سُوْرَۃُ الفَاتِحَة</span> </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

I guess you would like to keep myDropdown open, when you hover it, so I added the onmouseover/onmouseout effect also there.

And JS code is simple:

```
function show() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
}
function hide() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
}
```

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
}
function hide() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
}



function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #61CE70;
  color: blue;
  margin: 1px 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10pxpx;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropbtn {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url(https://search.png);
  float: input;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #086815;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 45px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align-last: max-width;
  border-color: #086815;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #067B0A4A;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-height: 550px;
  overflow: scroll;
  text-align-last: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  width: 390px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #7A7A7A;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}


/* ADD CSS */

div#myDropdown a span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}


/* width */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button  onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()"  class="dropbtn">SURAH</button>
  <div  onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()" id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search your Surah.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">1.Sureh Al-Fatihah <span>سُوْرَۃُ الفَاتِحَة</span> </a>
    <a href="#about">2.Sureh Al-Baqarah <span>سُوْرَۃُ الفَاتِحَة</span> </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the hovering part, you can achiveve it with CSS only:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Working example:

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #61CE70;
  color: blue;
  margin: 1px 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10pxpx;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


.dropbtn {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url(https://search.png);
  float: input;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #086815;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 45px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align-last: max-width;
  border-color: #086815;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #067B0A4A;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-height: 550px;
  overflow: scroll;
  text-align-last: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  width: 390px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #7A7A7A;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}


/* ADD CSS */

div#myDropdown a span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}


/* width */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">SURAH</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search your Surah.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">1.Sureh Al-Fatihah <span>سُوْرَۃُ الفَاتِحَة</span> </a>
    <a href="#about">2.Sureh Al-Baqarah <span>سُوْرَۃُ الفَاتِحَة</span> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```